# VBA to Extract Date from File Path

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a series of files to track in an excel spreadsheet. They are stored in folders by date. Sometimes the file is changed, then resubmitted, so the file path name is variable. The date format is constant 'YYYY MM DD'.

Examples:

G:\Inbox\Folder1\Received\2019 03 01\Final
G:\Inbox\Folder1\Received\2019 03 01\2019 03 02\2019 03 05\Final

Using excel VBA, how do I extract only the last date from the file path?

Comment: split() on "\" then the ubound - 1 will be the last date segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will do:

```
Sub test()

Dim MyPath As String, mps As Variant, mps_temp As String, mydate As Date, i As Integer

MyPath = "G:\Inbox\Folder1\Received\2019 03 01\2019 03 02\2019 03 05\Final"
mps = Split(MyPath, "\")

For i = LBound(mps) To UBound(mps)
    mps_temp = mps(UBound(mps) - i)
    If mps_temp Like "#### ## ##" Then
        mydate = DateSerial(Mid(mps_temp, 1, 4), Mid(mps_temp, 6, 2), Mid(mps_temp, 9, 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

msgbox mydate 

End Sub
```

Comment: That's odd, does it highlight any line in particular?

Comment: Try now with sub and dims added in case you missed that.

Comment: It does not error out now Daniel, however, when I insert mydate into a cell, I only get a 0 (zero)?

Comment: No. Came back as: 12:00:00 AM

Comment: What is the path string you are trying to extract the date from?

Comment: I believe the error is that some users have added a date to the filename, as well as the folder path. It must be hitting on the date in the filename.

Comment: Date in the filename is not an issue at all! Would you like to share an example of bad result? I can't help you without seeing the path that doesn't work for you. Everything should work fine and error free. Is the cell you entering data to formatted as 'Time'? This would display the date as midnight I suppose. Make sure cell is formatted as date.

Comment: The problem was in the naming of the folder - not your logic, Daniel. Once I addressed the folder naming, worked like a charm. Thanks for your patience with a novice. Much appreciated.

Comment: No prob, the code will work as long as folder name is in "YYYY MM DD" format, otherwise it will return incorrect results. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if you're happy with it :)

Comment: Another issue has come up, Daniel. I do not want to display 'thumbs.db' files or other system files. Is there a way to filter?

Comment: It might be worth creating separate post with all details as it's a different issue that needs looking at

Answer (score 1):

***ASSUMPTION(s)***:

1. the last date is in the position just before *\Final*

Consider:

```
Sub titan()
    Dim s As String, sDate As String, d As Date

    s = "G:\Inbox\Folder1\Received\2019 03 01\2019 03 02\2019 03 05\Final"
    arr = Split(s, "\")
    sDate = arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    arr2 = Split(sDate, " ")
    d = DateSerial(arr2(0), arr2(1), arr2(2))
    MsgBox d
End Sub
```

[image]

Parse the filepath.  Grab the **next-to-last** element.  Convert to date.

Comment: BadDogTitan mentioned that path is variable, your code is not going to work if the last folder with date is other than "arr(UBound(arr) - 1)". I like how you used array in DateSerial, it's clearer :)

Comment: Fantastic, Gary's Student. Works great.

Comment: @Daniel  **You are correct.**  I will list the assumptions at the top of the answer and let the Poster decide.

Comment: Regarding the assumption, will this still work if there are more folders after 'Final'? My sample data set did not include that, but now I see users are submitting files in folders after 'Final'. I will always only ever want the last date, however.

Comment: @BadDogTitan  No, it will not work............a different approach must be devised.............please update your question with more examples...............

Comment: @BadDogTitan the code I wrote will always take the last date no matter where it is, as long as it in "YYYY MM DD" format.